# Ubuntu 22.04 stops in kworker

Tags: 22.04, crash

After running Ubuntu 22.04 for a few hours, it crashes. It crashes completely and requires a physical reboot.
When this happens, the first process on top is kworker, as shown in the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBuZ7.jpg)

Comment: kworker itself is unlikely to be the culprit. You may find something useful at the bottom of `journalctl -b -1`. Which is the previous boot (change the -1 to -2 for the previous before that etc). Perhaps there was an error captured there? Has the system really locked up? When it next does this, try ALT-SysRQ then with ALT still pressed, press S (sync). If the disk like blinks, the kernel is still alive, and not hard-locked.